# Use the same function in Multiple inheritance in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to implement an interface with two classes with same methods.
Afterwards, I created a 4th class that inherits methods from the two classes.

So if I need to use a method from the class `hdfs_way`, I will pass a parameter 1 to the `__init__` of `use_FileSystem` class, or 2 if I want to use methods from the class `hdfs_way`.

My code works fine but I don't know if it is the best way to do something like that.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class FileSystemInterface:
  __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
  @abstractmethod
  def list_dirs(self):
    pass

class hdfs_way(FileSystemInterface):
  def list_dirs(self):
    print("HDFS WAY")
    return None

class java_way(FileSystemInterface):
  def list_dirs(self):
    print("JAVA WAY")
    return None 

class use_FileSystem(hdfs_way,java_way):
  def __init__(self,type_api):
    self.type_api = type_api

  def list_dirs(self):
    if(self.type_api == '1'):
      java_way.list_dirs(self)
    else:
      hdfs_way.list_dirs(self)

a = use_FileSystem('2')
a.list_dirs()
```

Comment: Seems like it would be easier not to use inheritance for this, and to pass an instance of `hdfs_way` or `java_way` to the `use_FileSystem` initialiser for it to use for these operations.

Comment: Why do you pass some obscure number to ``use_FileSystem`` instead of directly instantiating either ``hdfs_way`` or ``java_way``? Your class ``use_FileSystem`` doesn't inherit anything, it is just an obscure way to select the actual types.

Comment: I'd concur with @khelwood, the weird-ass dispatch thing could extend FileSystemInterface but it has no reason to extend the other two implementation, it should just *use* them (composition). Not that that seems useful in any way, `use_FileSystem` could just be a function which returns the proper implementation, it has no reason to even be a class.

Answer (score 1):

On a conceptual point of view, what you do is acceptable: if the same attribute of method exists in more than one base class, you must add an explicit override in the child class, possibly using the base classes implementation.

On a Pythonic point of view this is also correct: you use the unbound method from the base classes, and explicitely give them the object. What could be more Pythonic is the use of `super` but it only make sense if your hierarchy has a *natural* intermediary class:

```
                                   Child

               BaseA                               BaseB

ImplementationA1 ImplementationA2   ImplementationB1 ImplementationB2
   methodX                                               methodX
```

You could then write:

```
  def methodX(self):
    if(self.type_api == '1'):
      self.super(BaseA, self)()
    else:
      self.super(BaseB, self)()
```

(beware super looks for the first base class of BaseA or BaseB in above code, hence the intermediary base class...)

---

Anyway, on a theorical point of view, multiple inheritance if often seen as a questionable design, and many prefere a containment pattern (*has a* instead of *is a*) in that case. It is for example forbidden in Java language, and is known to cause maintenance headaches (diamond inheritance) in C++ language.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I reliaze that using inheritance it isn't the best idea to do my need,
The best way is to implement the design pattern Abstract Factory,

Please find below my code after the refactoring :

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class FileSystemInterface:
  __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

  @abstractmethod
  def list_dirs(self):
    pass

class HDFS_way(FileSystemInterface):
    def list_dirs(self):
      print("HDFS WAY")
      return None

class JAVA_way(FileSystemInterface):
  def list_dirs(self):
    print("JAVA WAY")
    return None 


class FileSystemFactory:
  HDFS_IMPL = 'HDFS'
  JAVA_IMPL = "JAVA"
  DEFAULT_IMPL= JAVA_IMPL

  @staticmethod
  def getFilesystem(implementation=None):
    if implementation is None:
      implementation = FileSystemFactory.DEFAULT_IMPL
    if(implementation == FileSystemFactory.JAVA_IMPL):
      return JAVA_way()
    else:
      return HDFS_way()

  @staticmethod
  def setDefault(implementation):
    FileSystemFactory.DEFAULT_IMPL = implementation



FileSystemFactory.setDefault(FileSystemFactory.HDFS_IMPL)
fs = FileSystemFactory.getFilesystem()
fs.list_dirs()
```

Answer (score -1):

In your implementation of list_dirs() in use_FileSystem, you are calling the parent class' list_dirs by either java_way.list_dirs(self) or hdfs_way.list_dirs(self). The way you called them is like you created the functions as a class method.

To denote the call is parent class's function, I think it's best if you use the word **super()**

```
class use_FileSystem(hdfs_way,java_way):
  def __init__(self,type_api):
    self.type_api = type_api

  def list_dirs(self):
    if(self.type_api == '1'):
      super(java_way, self).list_dirs()
    else:
      super(hdfs_way, self).list_dirs()
```